# Winrar command line compress specific files with date in name depending on current date

Tags: groovy, command-line, file-type, winrar

I'm trying to compress *SQL* server backup (`.bak`) files using *WinRAR* command line command. Here's the command I use:

```
def fileType = "*.bak"

"cmd /c \"${rarCmd}\" a ${rarName} ${parameters} ${sourceDir} ${fileType}".execute()
```

I've got these files in my folder:

```
Basket_backup_2014_07_30_010007.bak
Basket_backup_2016_07_31_010007.bak
Basket_backup_2016_08_05_010006.bak
Basket_backup_2016_08_05_010007.bak
```

I only want to compress the files that are created today. So how should I modify the `fileType` variable in order to compress files containing `2016_08_05` in their names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start **WinRAR** and click in menu **Help** on menu item **Help topics**. On tab **Contents** open list item **Command line mode** and click first on *Command line syntax* and you will see on opened help page:

> WinRAR <command> -<switch1> -<switchN> <archive> <files...> <@listfiles...> <path_to_extract\>

Now let us compare this line with your code line:

```
"${rarCmd}" a ${rarName} ${parameters} ${sourceDir} ${fileType}
```

There is obviously already the mistake in your code to specify after the command first the archive file name and then the switches instead of first the switches and next the archive file name.

And there should be no space between `${sourceDir}` and `${fileType}`, but a backslash character.

Then open in contents list the sublist **Switches** and click on *Alphabetic switches list*. Build your `parameters` with using this list while reading it from top to bottom. The most interesting switches for you are most likely

```
-cfg- -ep1 -ibck -inul -m5 -r- -tl -tn23h -y --
```

`-tn23h` means last modification date of file is within the last 23 hours (file time newer than current time minus 23 hours). You could also use `-tn1d` for file last modified within 1 day.

In case of using console version `Rar.exe` instead of GUI version `WinRAR.exe` use the text file `Rar.txt` in program files folder of *WinRAR* as this is the manual for the console version. There are some switches different between console and GUI version.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
def fileType = "*_${new Date().format('yyyy_MM_dd')}_*.bak"
```